# Pascal's triangle with slight variation

Tags: c++

I am just trying to print a pyramid pattern with slight variation but i can't get what i expect.

This should be the output when user enters 7 as input

```
1 7 7 1 5 6 1 
 1 6 1 0 5 1 
  1 4 6 4 1 
   1 3 3 1 
    1 2 1 
     1 1 
      1
```

But this is the output that i am getting.

```
1 6 15 20 15 6 1
 1 5 10 10 5 1
  1 4 6 4 1
   1 3 3 1
    1 2 1
     1 1
      1
```

my code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int N,c=1,blk,i,j;
    cin >> N;
    if(N>=5 && N<=21)
    {
        for(i=N-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
            for(blk=N-1;blk>=1+i;blk--)
            cout<<" ";
            for(j=0;j<=i;j++)
            {
                if (j==0||i==0)
                    c=1;
                else
                   c=c*(i-j+1)/j;
                cout<<c<<" ";
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should explain what is the logic behind the triangle you want to build. Not clear from the example you provide

Comment: I cannot access the page that you provide the link. Note that all useful information must be provided in the post

Comment: Please tell the the logic behind the expected triangle!

Comment: it's called pascal triangle it's working fine until the N=5 but thereafter original hackkerank question output is slightly different from the original pascal triangle

Comment: original pascal triangle's output is what i am getting. but the expected output is different

Comment: @JayarajRohan Okay got it... It is Power of 11 triangle. Digits overlap after 11^4.

Comment: can you explain in code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>

#define pb push_back
#define all(v) v.begin(), v.end()

std::string to_string(long double x) {
    std::ostringstream stream;
    stream.precision(0);
    stream << std::fixed << x;
    return stream.str();
}

std::vector<std::string> pow11(int n) {
    std::vector<std::string> v;
    for(long double i = 1; n > 0; i *= 11, n--)
       v.pb(to_string(i));
    std::reverse(all(v));
    return v;
}

int main() {
    int n, c = 0;
    std::cin >> n;
    auto v = pow11(n);
    for(auto &i : v) {
        for(int k = 0; k < c; k++)
            std::cout << " ";
        c++;
        for(auto &j : i)
            std::cout << j << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sample Input:

```
8
```

Sample Output:

```
1 9 4 8 7 1 7 1 
 1 7 7 1 5 6 1 
  1 6 1 0 5 1 
   1 4 6 4 1 
    1 3 3 1 
     1 2 1 
      1 1 
       1
```

Comment: @JayarajRohan It will work only for `n <= 18`. I think that using the properties of powers of 11 this can be done in lesser complexity. Also, you can change `int64` to some thing like `long double` to handle quite large `n` values.

Comment: yep i noticed that

Comment: Well I added that myself in the code. See the edited code. Now it supports large `n` values.